# NUXT 3 Module Error on adding ant-design-vue

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, ant-design-vue

I am trying to add **Ant Design Vue** as module into **Nuxt3** project.

```js
    import { fileURLToPath } from "node:url"
    import { defineNuxtModule } from "@nuxt/kit"
    export default defineNuxtModule({
      setup (_, nuxt) {
        nuxt.options.css.push("ant-design-vue/dist/antd.css")
      },
      hooks: {
        "components:dirs" (dirs) {
          dirs.push({
            path: fileURLToPath( new URL('../node_modules/ant-design-vue/lib', import.meta.url) ),
            pattern: '*/index.js',
            prefix: 'a',
          })
        }
      }
    })
```

But it gives an error:

**[nuxt] [request error] Only URLs with a scheme in: file, data are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'c:'**

I tried to use via `path.resolve(__dirname, '...')`, but unsuccessful

Node: v16.15.0
Nuxt: 3.0.0-rc.3
ant-design-vue: 3.2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 2 day research finally I got the working solution.

### Adding ant-design-vue and icons into NUXT 3 projects

1. Install deps

```bash
npm i ant-design-vue @ant-design/icons-vue unplugin-vue-components --save
```

2. Add it into the **nuxt.config** file

```js
// nuxt.config.ts
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite';
import { AntDesignVueResolver } from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers';

export default defineNuxtConfig({
 
  vite: {
    plugins: [
      Components({
        // add option {resolveIcons: true} as parameter for resolving problem with icons
        resolvers: [AntDesignVueResolver({resolveIcons: true})],
      }),
    ],
    // @ts-expect-error: Missing ssr key
    ssr: {
      noExternal: ['moment', 'compute-scroll-into-view', 'ant-design-vue','@ant-design/icons-vue'],
    },  
  },
})
```

3. Enjoy magic of auto-importing

Comment: this solves the problem, but it does create a components.d.ts in project root. I would like to integrate it with nuxt